# Multi-level wildcard DNS matched by *.domain.com?

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard-subdomain, round-robin

Q1: Does a DNS rule for *.domain.com match multi-level domain names? In other words, if I just set *.domain.com in my DNS records, will it match all of:

```
a.domain.com
b.a.domain.com
c.b.a.domain.com
```

as many levels deep as needed, with just that one wildcard DNS specifier?

We have a use case for multi-level DNS and I would like to confirm that we are doing the right thing in setting one wildcard DNS setting for the root domain.

Q2: will this work with round-robin DNS?

Comment: In less time than it took to write the question you could have created the entry and done a couple of nslookups to test it.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers: correct, I could have certainly tested it and made sure it worked, but I wasn't sure if that was the right thing to do or not. I was trying to ascertain if this was best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: yes. *.domain.com will match any domain above domain.com ex: a.domain.com a.a.domain.com a.a.a.domain.com etc.

Q2: This should work

If you want global pool of IP's

> *.domain.com IN A 1.1.1.1
>
> *.domain.com IN A 2.2.2.2
>
> *.domain.com IN A 3.3.3.3

this is ok and will work (tested in djbdns)